# Existing javascript function on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, html

How I can run existing javascript function with element which is created dynamically?

suppose I have.

```
function selectRow(object) {
  if (object.className == 'not-selected') object.className = 'selected';        
}
```

in html (this comes from ajax call dynamically)

```
<tr class="item-row" onclick="selectRow(this, <?php echo $i; ?>"><td>Row one</td></tr>
```

To clarify, is there a way to do it without rewriting every single function to `$(document).on('click', 'element', function() {` ...

Comment: Doesn't the code shown work? (Assuming `selectRow()` is global.)

Comment: it does not on dynamic elements but it works with other elements

Comment: The code shown should work even for dynamically added elements, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/7u9ryr1a/

Comment: it should work even on dynamically added elements , if it doesn't then i guess you'll have to reattach the event on the element in the `success: function(){}` in the ajax call (Still it should work , i wonder whats wrong??? )

Comment: I'm doing investigations, part by part at the moment and will post here asap I know. This is really old code, from 2005 or so, and this has been expanded "few" times with just js and now with jQuery

Comment: It seems radio button inside row(s) which were made dynamically, negated this effect. Radio buttons inside other rows were working because of new jQuery but new radio buttons (made dynamically) had to use $(document).on('click', 'element', function()... So TR was working but not the radio inside it (which made row again not selected because original jQuery did not work on dynamic elements). All the time were looking mistake from row it self :(